# Angular 10 array isn't changed although passed by reference

Tags: angular

I have multiple checkboxes in my component. Each group of checkboxes that has some logic connection has a field called checkedXXX to save the checked objects.

For example :

```
shops: Shop[];
checkedShop: Shop[];
products: Product[];
checkedProduct: Product[];
```

In my html code, for each checkbox I added a dedicated (change) method :

```
  <mat-checkbox
    (change)="onChangeShop($event,shop)"> {{shop.name}}
  </mat-checkbox>
```

In my code, I have a general method to handle every check/uncheck of checkbox and a method that handles specific uncheck/check that calls the previous method I mentioned :

```
  onChangeShop($event, shopArg){
    this.onChangeCheckbox($event, this.checkedShops, s=> s.id === shopArg.id , shopArg);
  }

  private onChangeCheckbox($event, arr: any[], filterLambda, checkedObject){
    const checkedObjectString = JSON.stringify(checkedObject);
    if ($event.checked){
      console.log('checkbox was checked : ' + checkedObjectString);
      arr.push(checkedObject);
    }
    else{
      console.log('checkbox was unchecked : ' + checkedObjectString);
      arr = arr.filter(obj => filterLambda(obj));
    }
  }
```

I noticed that the filter doesn't work. Even when the lambda returns false the orig array size isn't decreasing.

I tried to debug :

```
  console.log('checkbox was unchecked : ' + checkedObjectString);
  arr = arr.filter(obj => {
    console.log('filter result : ' + filterLambda(obj));
    return filterLambda(obj);
  });
```

and saw in my console the following :

```
checkbox was unchecked : {"...."}
filter result : false
checkbox was unchecked : {""}
filter result : false
```

but the orig size of the array wasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the problem in the end (I guess some references problem) but I found a cleaner and easier solution:

I added to my shop/product another field:

```
isSelected: boolean;
```

When I received the object from the onChange method I'm using the following logic:

```
  onChangeCheckbox($event, obj) {
    if ($event.checked){
      obj.isSelected = true;
      console.log('checkbox was checked : ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
    else {
      obj.isSelected = false;
      console.log('checkbox was unchecked : ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  }
```

In this way, there is no need to  have a dedicated method for each checkbox group.

In addition, you can also extend your original object and add this field to a new object that will be used only for your case.

Comment: A quick reminder - please refrain from "txtspk" constructions here, like "u" and "ur". Technical writing is generally expected - this is not a chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic of passing the `lambda` to your `filter` method. Below is the sample code for your reference-

```
let arr: any[] = [];
arr.push({ id: 12, value: 'test' }, { id: 1, value: 'test' });

const onChangeCheckbox = function (arr: any[], filterLambda) {
      arr = arr.filter(filterLambda);
      console.log('checkbox was unchecked : ' + arr.length);// checkbox was unchecked : 1
}
// Call the function
onChangeCheckbox(arr, (s) => s.id === 12);//
```